# Image class in C#

Tags: c#-2.0

Can anyone help me out in setting blank image using Image class in C#? I mean, i have few images to be displayed based on some manipulations.If any condition is met, i shouldn't display any image in tat case.And i dont hav any default image to display for the above said scenario.How can i implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
Image blank = new Bitmap(width, height);
```

This will produce a new image with the specified width and height (integers).

If you want the image to have a specific color, you will need to set each pixel with [`SetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx):

```
// Set each pixel in blank to black. Use a different Color.xxx if you wish
for (int Xcount = 0; Xcount < myBblankitmap.Width; Xcount++)
{
    for (int Ycount = 0; Ycount < blank.Height; Ycount++)
    {
        blank.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, Color.Black);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an actual default image (using an image editor of your choice) and display that.

Comment: thank u. And can the image take the back color of any control?

Comment: @swetha - You have full control over the color. You will have to set each pixel in turn.

Comment: Using System.Drawing.Graphics you don't have to set each pixel manually: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yysstebh.aspx